# (Lubuntu 18.04.1) Lxhotkey bug

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04

I can´t see all hotkeys present in *lxhotkey*!  The program doesn't have a vertical scrollbar but if I plug in a bigger monitor I can see the other hotkeys that were previously hidden.

Can I do something to fix this?

Comment: I think it's a bug. There should be a vertical scrollbar for users who have laptops or who use larger fonts. In any case, I prefer to edit *~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml* directly to change keybinds or mousebinds.

Comment: Please report bugs to developers. @DKBose your comment could be an answer imho - seems a good workaround

Comment: @Zanna I posted an answer but it's a bit general because there's no specific issue to address.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxhotkey/+bug/1801606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the drawback of *lxhotkeys* not displaying properly on some screens, it is relatively limited in what it provides.

If you want to get in deeper, getting familiar with *~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml* is worth the effort.

There's an old but nevertheless excellent article on the subject: [Openbox - Edit rc.xml to Gain Control](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201107/page08.html). It covers the structure of the xml code and provides information on the various subsections present in the file.

- Resistance
- Focus
- Placement
- Theme
- Desktops
- Resize
- Margins
- Dock
- Keyboard
- Mouse
- Menu
- Applications

Once you understand it and the related *menu.xml*, you can do most anything without needing a GUI.

And there's also the official [Openbox Wiki](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page).